# Applescript - How to save preferences

Tags: macos, applescript

I write Applescript and I try save "app" preferences (password). I can make this in file but I (think) must write full path to file :-/ How can I open a file without entering the full path or save and use in "preferences"?

```
set filePath to "macOS Sierra:Users:test:Desktop:pass.txt"
set pass to paragraphs of (read file filePath)

do shell script command user name theuser password pass with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't downvote this question, but I do see that it has some problems.

- The first step in [writing a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is to tell us what you searched for. What did you find? Have you made any progress toward a solution?
- It would also "help us help you" if you added *precisely* what your goal is, what you tried, and what didn't work in your attempts. It's unclear, for example, why you want to store some data in a file, but then do not want to include the full path to that file.
- Finally—and I say this in good faith and with your best interests in mind—your larger goal might perhaps be OK, but **storing a plaintext password in a file is a very bad practice**, on security grounds.

To move things forward, hopefully some of these will be directly applicable or helpful:

- If you wish to store a password natively in the macOS keychain from an applescript, consider using the [`security`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) shell command also via [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40).
- For an all-applscript route, I often see mentions of the third-party solution called [*Usable Keychain Scripting*](https://red-sweater.com/blog/170/usable-keychain-scripting), an applescript-to-app-to-keychain interface. Note! It appears unmaintained, and is 12 years old!
- You mentioned a 'preferences' file. If you wish to store data as key+value pairs, consider using macOS's ubiquitous preference-storage system, and its [`defaults`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) command, again via `do shell script`. It will allow you to write and read preferences without a loose file on your desktop.
- Lastly, to your direct question—again, you shouldn't do this with passwords!—but if you must reference a custom file, but do not wish to use a hard-coded path, applescript can find many folders by name using the `path to` it and expand the folder name into a full alias, e.g. `tell application "Finder" to size of (file "myData.bin" of folder (path to desktop folder from user domain))`. See [the `path to` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19) for usage and a full list of named folders.